# Flutter 2.0 too slow for first time

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, flutter2.0

I have upgraded to flutter 2.0.1 and tried running the flutter demo app in my android device even after an hour the message is still running gradle... is there a way to fix this or did i miss anything.

PS: it got build for web and launched in some 220 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to convert an Android App to Web and Desktop Apps but it just took around 20-40 seconds!
May be it is depending on the Machine, I guess. I'm running it on Ryzen 7 4800HS.

You can try:

`flutter clean.`

`flutter pub get.`

`flutter run.`